# Biopython with netbeans

Tags: biopython

I have python 2.7.3 and netbeans 8.0 I already installed the plugins for python and works properly but I would like to use biopython but nothing is shown in the output, no even a error mnessage, I already have numpy, matplotlib, reportlab. How I could execute them in netbeans?

kind regards

Comment: Just to clarify, you also installed the actual biopython package?

Comment: yes it is already installed in python27 folder along with numpy, matplotlib, etc

Comment: I think I found the problem, many thanks

Comment: Consider posting an answer to this question, how you solved it, so other people with the same problem can find help here. :)

Comment: It was my fault and I apologize for the waste of time, I had the wrong python version by default in netbeans beacuse I had python 3 installed before.           kind regards